# Spark 2.3 - Minikube - Kubernetes - Windows - Demo - SparkPi not found

Tags: windows, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to follow [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) but I am encountering an error.

In particular, when I run:

```
spark-submit.cmd --master k8s://https://192.168.1.40:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:spark --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

I get:

```
2018-03-17 02:09:00 INFO  LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl:54 - State changed, new state:
         pod name: spark-pi-driver
         namespace: default
         labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-798e78e46c5c4a11870354b4b89602c0, spark-role -> driver
         pod uid: c6de9eb7-297f-11e8-b458-00155d735103
         creation time: 2018-03-17T01:09:00Z
         service account name: default
         volumes: default-token-m4k7h
         node name: minikube
         start time: 2018-03-17T01:09:00Z
         container images: spark:spark
         phase: Failed
         status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=docker://5c3a1c81333b9ee42a4e41ef5c83003cc110b37b4e0b064b0edffbfcd3d823b8, image=spark:spark, imageID=docker://sha256:92e664ebc1612a34d3b0cc7522615522805581ae10b60ebf8c144854f4207c06, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=ContainerStateTerminated(containerID=docker://5c3a1c81333b9ee42a4e41ef5c83003cc110b37b4e0b064b0edffbfcd3d823b8, exitCode=1, finishedAt=Time(time=2018-03-17T01:09:01Z, additionalProperties={}), message=null, reason=Error, signal=null, startedAt=Time(time=2018-03-17T01:09:01Z, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={}), waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={})]
```

With `kubectl logs -f spark-pi-driver` telling me that:

```
C:\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7>kubectl logs -f spark-pi-driver
++ id -u
+ myuid=0
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
++ getent passwd 0
+ uidentry=root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash
+ '[' -z root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash ']'
+ SPARK_K8S_CMD=driver
+ '[' -z driver ']'
+ shift 1
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
+ readarray -t SPARK_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar;/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar' ']'
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*:/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar;/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ CMD=(${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java "${SPARK_JAVA_OPTS[@]}" -cp "$SPARK_CLASSPATH" -Xms$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Xmx$SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS $SPARK_DRIVER_CLASS $SPARK_DRIVER_ARGS)
+ exec /sbin/tini -s -- /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java -Dspark.executor.instances=1 -Dspark.driver.port=7078 -Dspark.driver.blockManager.port=7079 -Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster -Dspark.jars=/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar,/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar -Dspark.app.id=spark-798e78e46c5c4a11870354b4b89602c0 -Dspark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:spark -Dspark.master=k8s://https://192.168.1.40:8443 -Dspark.kubernetes.executor.podNamePrefix=spark-pi-fb36460b4e853cc78f4f7ec4d9ec8d0a -Dspark.app.name=spark-pi -Dspark.driver.host=spark-pi-fb36460b4e853cc78f4f7ec4d9ec8d0a-driver-svc.default.svc -Dspark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver -cp ':/opt/spark/jars/*:/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar;/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar' -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Dspark.driver.bindAddress=172.17.0.4 org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
```

It cannot find the SparkPi class. Yet, when I explore the `spark:spark` container, the JAR is inside:

```
\opt\spark\examples\jars:
spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

So the image was built correctly...

Any ideas what's wrong?

Help!!!

*Edit*

I have been doing some more testing. I did set up an AKS in Azure and launched the same Docker image getting the same error. I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/spark-job) instructions but using the same Docker image as in local through ACR.

Also, the .JAR was uploaded to Blob Storage and an URL used for the case of AKS. Still I got the exact same error.

This somehow makes me think the error might be in the way I build the image itself or in the way I build the .JAR more so than in some configuration of the Cluster itself.

Yet, no cigar.

Any ideas - or even an URL to get a working Spark 2.3 image - would be welcome.
I build the image in Windows. I will try to build it in Linux shortly, maybe that is the problem all along...

Thx

Comment: I am not a professional in Spark, but in your log, I found that `/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar` included in `SPARK_CLASSPATH` twice. Maybe it causes something like a cross-dependency?

Comment: If it is possible, try to use image `onlinehead/kubernetes-spark:v2.3.0`. That is my repo on DockerHub, I just build that image and Spark from scratch using clean sources of Spark repo. Maybe the clean build will help you.

Comment: Hi @AntonKostenko,
thanks for the image.

I did try minikube using your image but I am getting the same error using:

spark-submit.cmd --master k8s://https://192.168.1.39:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=onlinehead/kubernetes-spark:v2.3.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver https://aekiak8spark.blob.core.windows.net/jars/sparkPi

Comment: Also @AntonKostenko I tried with the JARS inside the image as:

     spark-submit.cmd --master k8s://192.168.1.39:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=onlinehead/kubernetes-spark:v2.3.0 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar

With the same luck...!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I tried to run example from WSL(Linux Subsystem for WSL) and it works.

It's look like a bug in Spark 2.3 version, that can not setup paths correctly in Windows environment.[Spark-on-k8s](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark) does not have behavior and works out of box.
So I found workaround to schedule Spark 2.3:

1. Setup WSL
2. Setup Spark Environment for Linux Subsystem
3. run in bash `./spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.1.40:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:spark --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-pi-driver local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is 3 months old but since I had similar issue and didn't found any valid answer, I'll post mine, maybe it'll help for the others:

As pointed here http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201804.mbox/%3cCAAOnQ7v-oeWeW-VMtV5fuonjPau8vafzQPheypzjv+2M8aEp=Q@mail.gmail.com%3e, the problem may come from different classpath separator. To test, I ended up by modifying /kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile from official Spark-Hadoop package. I added these 2 lines directly before `ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark` and my job could start:

```
COPY examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar /opt/spark/jars
COPY examples/jars/scopt_2.11-3.7.0.jar /opt/spark/jars
```

It's a workaround instead of proper solution but at least it lets to make the tests.

And `spark-submit` command looks like:

```
./bin/spark-submit.cmd  --master k8s://localhost:6445  --deploy-mode cluster  --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=2  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:latest --conf spark.app.name=spark-pi   local:///opt/spark/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

And I build Docker image like that: `docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .`