# spark-submit on kubernetes cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, minikube

I have created simple word count program jar file which is tested and works fine. However, when I am trying to run the same jar file on my `Kubernetes` cluster it's throwing an error. Below is my `spark-submit` code along with the error thrown.

```
spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name WordCount --class com.sample.WordCount --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=debuggerrr/spark-new:spark-new local:///C:/Users/siddh/OneDrive/Desktop/WordCountSample/target/WordCountSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar local:///C:/Users/siddh/OneDrive/Desktop/initialData.txt
```

The last `local` argument is the data file on which the wordcount program will run and fetch the results.

Below is my error:

```
    status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=null, image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5, imageID=, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=ContainerStateWaiting(message=Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5", reason=ImagePullBackOff, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={started=false})]
20/02/11 22:48:13 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: State changed, new state:
         pod name: wordcount-1581441237366-driver
         namespace: default
         labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-386c19d289a54e2da1733376821985b1, spark-role -> driver
         pod uid: a9e74d13-cf77-4de0-a16d-a71a21118ef8
         creation time: 2020-02-11T17:13:59Z
         service account name: default
         volumes: spark-local-dir-1, spark-conf-volume, default-token-wbvkb
         node name: minikube
         start time: 2020-02-11T17:13:59Z
         container images: gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5
         phase: Running
         status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=docker://7b46d9483cf22d94c7553455dd06a6a9530b2947a6db71d089cfe9dcce656c26, image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5, imageID=docker-pullable://gcr.io/spark-operator/spark@sha256:0d2c7d9d66fb83a0311442f0d2830280dcaba601244d1d8c1704d72f5806cc4c, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=true, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=ContainerStateRunning(startedAt=2020-02-11T17:18:11Z, additionalProperties={}), terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={started=true})]
20/02/11 22:48:19 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: State changed, new state:
         pod name: wordcount-1581441237366-driver
         namespace: default
         labels: spark-app-selector -> spark-386c19d289a54e2da1733376821985b1, spark-role -> driver
         pod uid: a9e74d13-cf77-4de0-a16d-a71a21118ef8
         creation time: 2020-02-11T17:13:59Z
         service account name: default
         volumes: spark-local-dir-1, spark-conf-volume, default-token-wbvkb
         node name: minikube
         start time: 2020-02-11T17:13:59Z
         container images: gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5
         phase: Failed
         status: [ContainerStatus(containerID=docker://7b46d9483cf22d94c7553455dd06a6a9530b2947a6db71d089cfe9dcce656c26, image=gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5, imageID=docker-pullable://gcr.io/spark-operator/spark@sha256:0d2c7d9d66fb83a0311442f0d2830280dcaba601244d1d8c1704d72f5806cc4c, lastState=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=null, waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), name=spark-kubernetes-driver, ready=false, restartCount=0, state=ContainerState(running=null, terminated=ContainerStateTerminated(containerID=docker://7b46d9483cf22d94c7553455dd06a6a9530b2947a6db71d089cfe9dcce656c26, exitCode=1, finishedAt=2020-02-11T17:18:18Z, message=null, reason=Error, signal=null, startedAt=2020-02-11T17:18:11Z, additionalProperties={}), waiting=null, additionalProperties={}), additionalProperties={started=false})]
20/02/11 22:48:21 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Container final statuses:


         Container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
         Container image: gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5
         Container state: Terminated
         Exit code: 1
20/02/11 22:48:21 INFO Client: Application WordCount finished.
20/02/11 22:48:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/02/11 22:48:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\siddh\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-1a3ee936-d430-4f9d-976c-3305617678df
```

How do I resolve this error? How can I pass the local file?
**NOTE**: JAR files and data files are present on my desktop and not in the docker image.

Comment: Added the answer. For the future posts please attach Driver Pod logs, you can get them by executing `kubectl logs <driver-pod-name>`. Also please refer [debugging Spark on Kubernetes docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/running-on-kubernetes.html#introspection-and-debugging) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I will edit the question once I run the job again. Also, added a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately passing local files to the job is not yet available for official release of Spark on Kubernetes. There is one solution in a Spark fork requiring to add [Resource Staging Server deployment](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management) to the cluster, but it is not included in the released builds.

Why it is not so easy to support? Imagine how to configure the network communication between your machine and Spark Pods in Kubernetes: in order to pull your local jars Spark Pod should be able to access you machine (probably you need to run web-server locally and expose its endpoints), and vice-versa in order to push jar from you machine to the Spark Pod your `spark-submit` script needs to access Spark Pod (which can be done via Kubernetes Ingress and requires several more components to be integrated).

The solution Spark allows is to store your artefacts (jars) in the http-accessible place, including hdfs-compatible storage systems. Please refer the [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#dependency-management).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. It cleared my couple of doubts. What I understood from the answer is that I need to create a deployment  by using the yaml file on below link: https://github.com/ifilonenko/spark-on-k8s/blob/master/kubernetes-resource-staging-server.yaml and latter on I can use spark-submit as per my code in the question and then it can identify the jar from my system. Am I correct? Please correct me if I am wrong. I am a newbie to this so, kinda in understanding process. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what needs to be changed in my existing code?

Comment: You should use `spark-submit` and build Spark image out of [this repo](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark). The feature shouldn't work with the official Spark versions. Also you need to add `--conf spark.kubernetes.resourceStagingServer.uri=http://<address-of-any-cluster-node>:31000 ` to your `spark-submit` script and provide the path to your local file as `./path/to/file` (without `local://`). Note that the feature is experimental and is not recommended to be used in production. Other your assumptions are correct.

Comment: When you say create a image of out the github repo, what does it mean actually? Can I use my existing container image mentioned in the code? Also, the other property you mentioned for resourceStagingServer.uri, so, can I pass kubernetes cluster url by usinig kubectl cluster-info command ?

Comment: Staging server URI is the URI of the [deployment](https://github.com/ifilonenko/spark-on-k8s/blob/master/kubernetes-resource-staging-server.yaml). It should be accessible from you machine, which means that you should create LoadBalancer of NodePort Service for it.
You canNOT use your image, because (if it is built out of the official [Spark release code](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.4.4)) it has no dependencies on the RSS (resource staging server) and it'll not fetch the JAR from RSS.

Comment: Where can I get the URI of deployment? Can I get it from the Kubernetes dashboard once I create my deployment? As I can see from the YAML file that I can use 31000 as the port number but not sure about the URI. Also, can I use kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0 image for the containers? If not can you guide me how to use that spark github repo for creating my own custom image. Is there any link for that?

Comment: How about this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images for my problem? Still, I am not sure how to get kubernetes/dockerfiles directory as mentioned in this link. Also, how if I use https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile file for creating a image and pushing it in my docker hub portal. Your thoughts on this? I am actually confused about what would be the ideal way of solving my problem in a more efficient manner. Can you guide me step by step? Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: I am already taking efforts but I feel I am not on the right path. So, in this case, I need your guidance in order to ensure my efforts shouldn't be wasted

Comment: I created my own docker image from this  debuggerrr/spark-new:spark-new which is pushed to docker hub and with the help of this I created a master and worker service for spark and was able to invoke spark-shell and pyspark. Can I use the same image for my problem?

Comment: How to get RSS deployment URI: please read the docs on how to expose Kubernetes Deployment endpoints with [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), in the RSS.yaml example [NodePort Service](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark/blob/branch-2.2-kubernetes/conf/kubernetes-resource-staging-server.yaml#L67-L79) is used and you can use the IP of any Kubernetes Node in your cluster to access it.

Comment: You can use `kubespark/spark-driver:v2.2.0-kubernetes-0.5.0` image. You can find Dockerfiles [here](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark/tree/branch-2.2-kubernetes/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker-minimal-bundle/src/main/docker), which you can use a the basement for extending. Also please refer [this guide](https://github.com/apache-spark-on-k8s/spark/blob/branch-2.2-kubernetes/docs/running-on-kubernetes.md) for more details.

Comment: Okay, I will try it and will let you know

Comment: I came across similar problems and I read that they were talking about putting jar file in the docker image of container under some /opt folders. Can you help me what is this all about ?

Comment: For eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49331570/spark-2-3-minikube-kubernetes-windows-demo-sparkpi-not-found/49831100#49831100

Answer (score 2):

download the `spark` precompiled package from [spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.4/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz). put your `jar` inside `examples` folder

```
 tree -L 1
.
├── LICENSE
├── NOTICE
├── R
├── README.md
├── RELEASE
├── bin
├── conf
├── data
├── examples  <---
├── jars
├── kubernetes
├── licenses
├── monitoring
├── python
├── sbin
└── yarn
```

then build a `docker` image.

```
docker build -t spark-docker:v0.1 -f -f ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .
docker push spark-docker:v0.1
```

Now run `spark-submit`

```
spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name WordCount --class com.sample.WordCount --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=debuggerrr/spark-docker:v0.1 local:///C:/Users/siddh/OneDrive/Desktop/WordCountSample/target/WordCountSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar local:///C:/Users/siddh/OneDrive/Desktop/initialData.txt
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks for the help @devnull

Comment: Just a doubt what should be the source path for putting the jar file. Should it be `/examples/jars/myjar.jar` or can I put it outside the `jars` folder? And what exact change needs to be done in the `Dockerfile` code?

Comment: So when you made the `Docker` Image the example `jar` already packaged so you can do like `spark-submit --master k8s://https://192.168.99.101:8443 --deploy-mode cluster --name WordCount --class com.sample.WordCount --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=debuggerrr/spark-docker:v0.1 local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar <<arg>>`

Comment: You should also copy the file you want to do a word count or just use any file which is already in the image  `....... local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar /opt/spark/README.md`