# Spark on Kubernetes "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm trying to execute spark jar in Kubernetes cluster and getting the following error

> Local jar SparkWordCount.jar does not exist. ClassNotFoundException

I have found the issue - "SparkWordCount.jar" is not present in the docker image "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5". I have to create a docker image with "SparkWordCount.jar". I just don't know to create a dockerfile to build the docker image with Spark jar. Can anybody help with that?

The following is my code

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-sales-driver4
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainClass: com.example.WordCount
  mainApplicationFile: "/user/Sivaranjani/workspaces/SparkWordCount.jar"
  sparkVersion: "2.4.5"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  volumes:
    - name: "test-volume"
      hostPath:
        path: "/tmp"
        type: Directory
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.5
    serviceAccount: spark
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.5
    volumeMounts:
      - name: "test-volume"
        mountPath: "/tmp"

Executed below command:
kubectl create -f spark.yaml

Below is the error log:

++ id -u
+ myuid=0
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
+ set +e
++ getent passwd 0
+ uidentry=root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
+ set -e
+ '[' -z root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash ']'
+ SPARK_K8S_CMD=driver
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ shift 1
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ PYSPARK_ARGS=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ R_ARGS=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' '' == 2 ']'
+ '[' '' == 3 ']'
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=172.17.0.6 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class com.example.WordCount spark-internal
20/03/12 05:51:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/03/12 05:51:36 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar /user/Sivaranjani/workspaces/SparkWordCount.jar does not exist, skipping.
20/03/12 05:51:36 WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load com.example.WordCount.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:806)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/03/12 05:51:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/03/12 05:51:36 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-33e36019-a7b9-413b-8ab4-f411eae07fbc
```

Comment: jar file is not reachable. you have to upload it or set it in hostpath and you can try again.

Comment: Could you please help in understanding where exactly the jar needs to be uploaded?

Comment: you can add file inside node directory `/tmp` and change path in config as per `/tmp`

Comment: Facing same issue again:                                                                      
20/03/12 07:25:10 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar /tmp/SparkWordCount.jar does not exist, skipping.
20/03/12 07:25:10 WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load com.example.WordCount.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.WordCount

Comment: I have found the issue.. "SparkWordCount.jar" is not present in the docker image "gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v2.4.5". I have to create a docker image with  "SparkWordCount.jar". I just don't know to create dockerfile to build the docker image with Spark jar. Could you please help with that?

Comment: Even I was trying to do it. Can you check this link and try the second answer and let me know whether it works [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174548/spark-submit-on-kubernetes-cluster]

Comment: Hey!! I found the solution..                                                                                          
1. While building dockerfile set context path.                                                            
  eg.  docker image build -t spark-operator:v1 /Users/Sivaranjani/Documents/Containers/Kubernetes/                                                       Here the context path is - /Users/Sivaranjani/Documents/Containers/Kubernetes/                             2. Place your jar file & dockerfile in context path